# addEventListener и getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

есть html:

```
<div id="arr">
   <div class="test">sdvsdvsdv</div>
   <div class="test">4349567294</div>
</div>
```

нужно с помощью addEventListener, getElementById и document.getElementsByClassName без использования JQUERY при клике на `<div class="test"></div>` получить html значение элемента, на который кликнули.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать например так: https://jsfiddle.net/matkdLxf/

Тоже самое с помощью getElementsByClassName: https://jsfiddle.net/23w21c3z/

```js
var test_items = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

for (var i = 0; i < test_items.length; i++) {
    test_items[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
     result.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }, false);
}
```

```css
#result {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="arr">
    <div class="test">sdvsdvsdv</div>
    <div class="test">4349567294</div>
</div>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: думал без цикла как-то можно, т.к. в jq это делается всё просто. значит буду делать так, как Вы показали. спасибо)

Comment: @ikerya, а как вы думали это работает внутри jQuery?))

Comment: @ikerya, внутри себя jQuery использует свою функцию `each`(тот же цикл) для выполнения функций на всех выбранных элементах

Comment: @IonDen `$(".test").click(function(e) {});` я не думаю, я знаю :)

Comment: @ikerya, и как раз **внутри** `click` вызывается _each_. Поэтому если вынести цикл в отдельную функцию - будет то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Если все элементы .test лежат в #arr, то можно обойтись без цикла: https://jsfiddle.net/cauo1755/

```
var element = document.getElementById('arr');
element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target; // элемент по которому кликнули
    var value = target.innerHTML;
    alert(value);
}, false);
```

Comment: Если внутри `.test` лежит ещё что-нибудь, то не прокатит

Comment: автор не ставил такой задачи. однако опровергну ваше утверждение, `e.target` это элемент, по которому был клик, поэтому уровень вложенности не имеет значения. https://jsfiddle.net/cauo1755/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cauo1755/2/ кликайте на Карла

Comment: Ну и то, что автор такого не написал в вопросе, может означать не отсутствие такой задачи, а то, что он просто не посчитал это важным и решил не писать или забыл написать, это во-первых; во-вторых, у пришедших из гугла такая задача может и стоять.)

Comment: Я представил решение в рамках заданного автором вопроса, зачем делать "мотоцикл" когда вполне хватит "велосипеда" для конкретной задачи. Что касательно Вашего примера, когда мы кликаем на слово `Карл`, в `e.target` мы получим именно тот элемент, по которому попали, для верстки `<div class="test"><span>Карл у</span> Клары украл кораллы</div>` данный подход не рассчитан.

Comment: Именно про это и написан мой первый комментарий. Но кто вам сказал, что хватит «велосипеда»? Может, автор вопроса скрывает от нас то, что планирует к «велосипеду» приклеить «движок» и получить «мотоцикл»; пока сам не скажет, ничего точно утверждать нельзя :)

Comment: Возможно автор конструирует еще более сложный механизм, но нам этого не узнать, пока он сам не расскажет. Наша цель, задать автору направление, что бы он смог решить свою задачу, ответ демонстрирует один из возможных вариантов подхода к решению. Опять же повторюсь, все зависит от конкретной цели. Считаю что в рамках заданного вопроса ответ дан корректно. Надеюсь убедил)